# Heroku push rejected, failed to install gems via Bundler Rice 1.4.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

I can't seem to push to heroku after using the rice gem (1.4.3). I always recieve the following error:

```
Installing rice (1.4.3)
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
   checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
   checking for gawk... no
   checking for mawk... mawk
   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
   checking for g++... g++
   checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
   checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
   checking whether we are cross compiling... no
   checking for suffix of executables...
   checking for suffix of object files... o
   checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
   checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
   checking for style of include used by make... GNU
   checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
   checking for ranlib... ranlib
   checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   checking for ruby.h... yes
   checking for node.h... no
   checking for ruby/node.h... no
   checking for version.h... no
   checking for env.h... no
   checking host system type... (cached) x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   checking for doxygen... no
   configure: WARNING: doxygen not found - will not generate any doxygen documentation
   checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
   configure: creating ./config.status
   config.status: creating Makefile
   config.status: creating rice/Makefile
   config.status: creating test/Makefile
   config.status: creating sample/Makefile
   config.status: creating ruby/Makefile
   config.status: creating ruby/lib/Makefile
   config.status: creating test/ext/Makefile
   config.status: creating ruby/lib/mkmf-rice.rb
   config.status: creating rice/detail/ruby_version_code.hpp
   config.status: creating rice/config.hpp
   config.status: rice/config.hpp is unchanged
   config.status: executing depfiles commands
   make
   Making all in rice
   make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/rice'
   make  all-am
   make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/rice'
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Class.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Class.Tpo -c -o Class.o Class.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Class.Tpo .deps/Class.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Data_Type.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Data_Type.Tpo -c -o Data_Type.o Data_Type.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Data_Type.Tpo .deps/Data_Type.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Director.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Director.Tpo -c -o Director.o Director.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Director.Tpo .deps/Director.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Exception.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Exception.Tpo -c -o Exception.o Exception.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Exception.Tpo .deps/Exception.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Identifier.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Identifier.Tpo -c -o Identifier.o Identifier.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Identifier.Tpo .deps/Identifier.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Module.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Module.Tpo -c -o Module.o Module.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Module.Tpo .deps/Module.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Object.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Object.Tpo -c -o Object.o Object.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Object.Tpo .deps/Object.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT String.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/String.Tpo -c -o String.o String.cpp
   mv -f .deps/String.Tpo .deps/String.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Struct.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Struct.Tpo -c -o Struct.o Struct.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Struct.Tpo .deps/Struct.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Symbol.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Symbol.Tpo -c -o Symbol.o Symbol.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Symbol.Tpo .deps/Symbol.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT VM.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/VM.Tpo -c -o VM.o VM.cpp
   mv -f .deps/VM.Tpo .deps/VM.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Arg_operators.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Arg_operators.Tpo -c -o Arg_operators.o Arg_operators.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Arg_operators.Tpo .deps/Arg_operators.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT Address_Registration_Guard.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/Address_Registration_Guard.Tpo -c -o Address_Registration_Guard.o Address_Registration_Guard.cpp
   mv -f .deps/Address_Registration_Guard.Tpo .deps/Address_Registration_Guard.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT check_ruby_type.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/check_ruby_type.Tpo -c -o check_ruby_type.o `test -f 'detail/check_ruby_type.cpp' || echo './'`detail/check_ruby_type.cpp
   mv -f .deps/check_ruby_type.Tpo .deps/check_ruby_type.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT demangle.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/demangle.Tpo -c -o demangle.o `test -f 'detail/demangle.cpp' || echo './'`detail/demangle.cpp
   mv -f .deps/demangle.Tpo .deps/demangle.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT method_data.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/method_data.Tpo -c -o method_data.o `test -f 'detail/method_data.cpp' || echo './'`detail/method_data.cpp
   mv -f .deps/method_data.Tpo .deps/method_data.Po
   g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -MT protect.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/protect.Tpo -c -o protect.o `test -f 'detail/protect.cpp' || echo './'`detail/protect.cpp
   mv -f .deps/protect.Tpo .deps/protect.Po
   rm -f librice.a
   ar cru librice.a Class.o Data_Type.o Director.o Exception.o Identifier.o Module.o Object.o String.o Struct.o Symbol.o VM.o Arg_operators.o Address_Registration_Guard.o check_ruby_type.o demangle.o method_data.o protect.o
   ranlib librice.a
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/rice'
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/rice'
   Making all in test
   make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/test'
   Making all in ext
   make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/test/ext'
   /usr/local/bin/ruby -I/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/ruby/lib -C t1 extconf.rb --with-cppflags="-I/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3" --with-libpath="/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/rice"
   checking for main() in -lrice... yes
   creating Makefile
   /usr/local/bin/ruby -I/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/ruby/lib -C t2 extconf.rb --with-cppflags="-I/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3" --with-libpath="/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/rice"
   checking for main() in -lrice... yes
   creating Makefile
   make -C t1 all
   make[3]: Entering directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/test/ext/t1'
   g++ -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3  -I/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/ruby/lib/include -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -Wall -g -o t1.o -c t1.cpp
   g++ -shared -o t1.so t1.o -L/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/rice -Wl,-R/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/rice -L. -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -L/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/ruby/lib/lib   -lrice -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lruby-static -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
   /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libruby-static.a(array.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
   /usr/local/lib/libruby-static.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   make[3]: *** [t1.so] Error 1
   make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/test/ext/t1'
   make[2]: *** [t1_all] Error 2
   make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/test/ext'
   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
   make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/test'
   make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_2mw894a3yrw66/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rice-1.4.3/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing rice (1.4.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install rice -v '1.4.3'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:happytyme-dev.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:happytyme-dev.git'
```

I've ran gem install rice -v '1.4.3' locally and all is good. I've also done bundle update, bundle install, git add . (Gemfile and Gemfile.lock), git commit -m "Creating gems" but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I encounter quite the same error, trying to use bundler for installing our dev application on a fresh ubuntu install. The only pointer I found actually ishttp://tomcopeland.blogs.com/juniordeveloper/2009/07/the-subversion-ruby-bindings-and-the-relocation-r_x86_64_32-error.html and https://github.com/jasonroelofs/rice/issues/18